# Request to merge 2 tags

Tags: discussion, mergers

[image-editing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing) and [photo-editing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/photo-editing/info) are the same, shouldn't we merge them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are indeed the same. They have been merged and a synonym was created as well to prevent future confusion.